# Custom field from package not editable

Tags: managed-package, custom-field

We have added a custom Picklist field to the Contact object with a few default options.
In DE everything works great and looks fine.

Upon installing this managed package in our Production site and adding it to a custom layout we see it but the picklist seems "empty" - meaning we cannot choose any of the options we have defined in the Developers edition.

I should mention that we have no problem writing to this field via Data Loader, I have no problem seeing this field w/custom triggers etc, meaning the field is there and installed properly.  I am even able to see the default options for the picklist which I have defined in DE in the production site.

I have looked into field security and set everything to "editable" but to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Picklist values are set per record type](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_recordtype.htm). If you have multiple record types, is it possible this field has no values set for that record type in production yet has them set in the DE org?

To add these values to your record type, navigate to your custom object. On that page, you should see the Record Types section:

[image: Record Types Section]

Click the Record Type Label to go into the detail view of that Record Type.

[image: Detail View of Record Type]

Here you will see the Picklists Available for Editing related list. Your picklist should now be there. Click the Edit link to take you to the page that sets the available values.

[image: Available Value Page]

In your scenario, everything should appear under the Available column. Simply move the values you want selectable under the Selected Values column. Rinse and repeat for each record type.

Comment: Hi Jesse, thanks a lot for the prompt reply! I think we're on to something, but it's the other way around.  I have the Record Types in the production environment but not in the DE..  what should I do?

Comment: I will update my answer with steps on how to resolve this.

Comment: Hi Jesse, thanks a lot, you've helped us a great deal!